# spark UI index partition

Tags: apache-spark

[image]

The Spark UI is showing this columns. Is the column "index" matching with the partition number ? Index 0 matches with partition number 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for every stage transformation you will see there is index started with 0 so you can say it is index of the partition and id is incremented so dont be confuse with index and id when you see another transformation you see there is again index started with 0.

Comment: Using a hash partitiong the partition index is calculated with keys.hashcode() % numpartitions. Is this value matching with the index column?

Comment: @syl No t will not because spark internally using hash partitioner for shuffle RDD so it is not same for index column and you cant assign partition ID spark internally generate it. if it is helpful then pls accept the answer :)